# elasticsearch nest groovy script where value doesn't exist

Tags: groovy, elasticsearch

I'm trying to make a script that can modify my score. So I made this:

```
if (!(doc['score_mod'].empty)) {
    _score * doc['score_mod'].value
}
```

but now I have a type called `web_page` that doesn't have the `score_mod` value and it's being generated via: https://github.com/codelibs/elasticsearch-river-web . So I can't mannually put the value in when it's being genereated.

Is there a way that I could have a static score for the `web_page` or have the groovy script check if that value exists?

The current code fails for the `web_pages` results, but for the ones with a `score_mod` value it works just fine

Comment: Have you tried `_score * (doc['score_mod']?.value ?: 1)` so it will default to 1 if `score_mod` is missing (or considered `false`)

Comment: Nope, never used groovy before, but it seems to work so thanks!

Comment: Cool!  Added as an answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the elvis operator and the `?.` shortcut operator like so:

```
_score * (doc['score_mod']?.value ?: 1)
```

So if `doc['score_mod']` is `null`, or `value` is null (or zero, or empty) it will default to `1` (and multiply that by `_score`)